# action is not getting mapped in struts

Tags: struts2

struts.xml

```
  <struts>
<!-- Configuration for the default package. -->
<package name="default"  extends="struts-default">
     <action name="HelloWorld" class="vaannila.HelloWorld">
  <result name="SUCCESS">/success.jsp</result>
 </action>
 </package>
</struts>
```

web.xml

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

index.jsp

```
  <%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World</title>
  </head>
   <body>
    <s:form action="HelloWorld" >
        <s:textfield name="userName" label="User Name" />
        <s:submit />
    </s:form>
</body>
```

success.jsp

HelloWorld.java

```
   package vaannila;


public class HelloWorld {

private String message;

private String userName;

public HelloWorld() {
}


  public String execute()  {



    setMessage("Hello " + getUserName());
    return "SUCCESS";
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}


public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}


public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}


public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}}
```

error message i am getting is

HTTP Status 404 - There is no Action mapped for action name HelloWorld.

i am using netbeans ide 6.8

struts.xml ,web.xml file is in WEB-INF directory .
Source Package->vannilla->HelloWorld is the action location of action class.

can anyone help me

Comment: Move `struts.xml` to any `classpath` (`[project]\src` or `WEB-INF\classes` or `etc`)

Comment: yes it worked.thks....but why netbeans is creating struts.xml in web-inf...when i shifted file in source packages it worked.what is the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems problem in web.xml file try to change filter class to filter dispatcher then try.. i hope it will work fine.

struts2

```
   <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher </filter-class>
```

Comment: There is no wrong in `web.xml`, `FilterDispatcher` is deprecated and replaced by `StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter`

Comment: yes i know that, but, try to change it with filterdispatcher then see, if still not mapped message comes,then we will try other things, because rest of the code seems fine to me.